# How to echo a array list comma separated as a data attribute?

Tags: php, wordpress

I run the following:

```
// array of images
$images = get_attached_media('image' );
// The following prints each image src and srcset 
// in a img element wrapper in a container div
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $ximage =  wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID,'medium');
    $img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $image->ID, 'medium' );
    echo '<div class="col"><img class="img-fluid" src="' .$ximage[0] . '" srcset="'.$img_srcset.'"></div>';
}
```

Span attribute

```
// With the following I am trying to loop over the array 
// and output each one separated with a comma as a data attribute
<span class="imgs_span" data-time="
  <?php foreach($images as $value){ 
    echo $value . ", ";}; 
  ?>">
</span>
```

But I get nothing at all

Comment: what is in `$images` ?

Comment: @Scuzzy it's an array, i wrote it as a comment in the question code

Comment: What does your http servers error log file say? That should _always_ be the first place to look when programming php in a web environment...

Comment: if `$images` is an array of objects as per [this documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media), then simply doing an echo on `$value` wont suffice. what part of the image object are you wishing to print in your data-time attribute?

Comment: I agree with @Scuzzy. I would output with `json_encode($images)` in order to know the right format and index to use, then make your edits

Comment: @Yuri yes I get the full object like that and it outputs it correctly, but I only need the value

Comment: Can you give us an example of the desired html outcome perhapps?

Comment: Which value? `get_attached_media()` will return an array of WP_Post objects. Here you can see the list of values you can read out of it [LINK](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$images` var is an array of objects, so you should select the desired attribute to show it, for example:

```
<span class="imgs_span" data-time="<?php foreach($images as $k => $value){$attr = ($k == count($images) - 1) ? $value->post_date : $value->post_date . ", "; echo $attr;};?>"></span>
```

The full attributs list of WP_Post class with the description from the [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)

Comment: Downvote since [get_attached_media()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media) returns an array of objects. so that's what `$images` is..

Comment: Apparently $images holds an array of objects. Are you sure you want to implode() that and echo the result?

Comment: @T.AKROUT: It will have an extra comma at the end of the string in final output. How will you remove that?

Comment: @d.coder, post edited to remove the extra comma at the end

Answer (score -1):

If it is 1D array, you can use `implode()`

```
<span class="imgs_span" data-time="<?php echo implode(",", $images); ?>"></span>
```

==========================

As `$images` is an array of WP_Post type object then you can use `array_map()` just before `implode()`:

```
<span class="imgs_span" data-time="<?php 
echo implode(",", array_map(function($item){ return $item->post_date; }, $images); 
?>"></span>
```

Comment: Apparently `$images` holds an array of objects. Are you sure you want to `implode()` that and `echo` the result?

Comment: Downvote since [get_attached_media()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media) returns an array of objects. so that's what `$images` is..